# intuitive way of thinking about combination in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a certain problem on an assignment which I am a little confused on. My task is to use a select statement to output all possible pairs of "singer" from table "singers1" and "coach" from table "coaches1". No need for duplicates, just the format singer,coach for all possible singers and coaches. I am no expert but i believe some type of union might be the right path to take? Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  think `cross join`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont really give the code as you said it is an assignment for you. But the hint is `cross join` as suggested by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)

The SQL `CROSS JOIN` produces a result set which is the number of rows in the first table multiplied by the number of rows in the second table, if no WHERE clause is used along with `CROSS JOIN`. This kind of result is called as Cartesian Product.

Read more about it [here](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php)